# Is it possible to execute a "C" statement without a semicolon

Tags: c, syntax, abstract

Post an example to execute a "C" statement without semicolon( ; )

Comment: What is this?  Homework?

Comment: That's no a good question.. please be more specific!
void main(void) {}  -- A statement without ';'

Comment: @Shirkrin: Function definition != statement

Comment: Why close this? Why "not a real question"? It does seem like one to me.

Comment: It's a question: "Is it?". It's programming related (related to the C language). I may be a candidate for CW, but it is a legitimate question.

Comment: It's a legitimate question. trigger happy today uh?

Comment: I see a dangerous (I hope occasional) tendency in this community to close as not a real question when the question is too useless from a "real code" point of view, or too "newbie". Please let's try not to create a stronghold. I've seen this happen already too many times. If this is homework, so be it, we are not there to look into people's decision not to do their homeworks, except when blatant. This is a legitimate question, and deserves a legitimate answer, not -1 and not 4 closes. Thanks.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Although it's not exactly the most useful question, it clearly is a programming related question.

Comment: Please be careful with editing. The original question clearly had the concept of whether it was possible to **execute** the statement. The current wording leaves this out completely. This is now a different question to the one posed.

Comment: @Charles, that makes a difference? Thought not. Will fix.

Comment: Well yes. `{}` is a statement, but it's not a valid C program so it couldn't be executed until you add some more 'stuff'. Would you then need to add a `;` somewhere? It's a valid concern IMHO.

Comment: I can see your point, but what was asked was not a complete C program, but a statement. You can place it inside a function and compile it into a library instead of an executable. I mean, no need for main (and return codes).

Comment: An interesting point, is whether `{}` is executed or not. If the compiler generates a `NOP` for it, then it is. If the compiler optimizes it away to nil, then it isn't. But you can also argue if the execution goes through that piece of code where `{}` is located, it was executed in a symbolic way...

Answer (score 10):

This line is a statement:

```
while (0) { }
```

Comment: how 'bout `while (1) { }`? At least you get some work done :)

Comment: And there's another interesting fact about the `1` vs `0`. The one with the `0` can be optimized away to nothing, while the one with the `1` cannot.

Comment: for (;;) {} .. crap, coded myself right out of a clever comment.

Comment: There was a very long and tedious discussion on news group comp.std.c about whether the compiler should be able to optimize away useless loops like the 'while (1) { }' loop.

Answer (score 8):

You can an expression in an `if()` as long as it evaluates to a scalar (integer, floating point number or pointer).

```
if (expr, 0) {}
```

According to the C grammar, `expr` is an expression. `if(expr){}` is a `selection_statement`, so this would match the bill.

Note that the `,0` isn't always necessary since the body of the `if()` is empty. So these would be equivalent statements, if `expr` returns a scalar:

```
if (expr) {}
while (expr, 0) {}
while (expr && 0) {}
while (expr || 0) {}
```

All would evaluate the expression once.

Comment: That won't make it a statement, but an expression. The whole thing (the if and the braces), is a statement, though.

Comment: Isn't a function call a statement, too?

Comment: when used inside an expression, it is an expression.

Comment: No, a function call is an expression which evaluates to its return value.

Comment: +1 This answer provides a statement and a placeholder for doing things.

Comment: A function call only "becomes" a statement when you add the precious semicolon.

Comment: Okay, i checked the C grammar. An "expression statement" is an expression followed by ";", so an expression isn't also a statement unless it's terminated by ";". But "if(expr){}" is a statement.

Answer (score 3):

**Wrong answer**

... with a new right answer below.

```
int main(void)
{
}
```

The pair of braces in the definition of `main` is a *compound-statement* which is one of the valid forms for a *statement*.

**Edit:** although a *statement* can be a *compound-statement*, and a *function-body* consists of a *compound-statement*, when the *compound-statement* is a function-body, it's not a *statement*.

**Edit, Edit:**

This program does contain a *statement* which is executed, though:

```
int main(void)
{
    if (1) {}
}
```

Comment: Hmm, don't see a statement there - just a declaration and an empty function body.

Comment: A function body consists of a compound statement.

Comment: The body if main is a (compound) statement according to the C grammar.

Comment: Only the body is a statement. The whole of the code posted is a function definition.

Comment: Oh, I get you. Although a _compound statement_ can be a _function-body_ or a _statement_, when it's a _function-body_ it's not technically a _statement_.

Comment: I was trying to post an example which was a complete program, most of the other answers were posting snippets from which it's not trivially obvious that execution of the statement can occur with adding a `;` somewhere to complete the program.

Comment: The pair of braces *is* a statement. The function header plus the braces is not.

Comment: Not it's not _statement_, only a _compound-statement_. A _compound-statement_ can either be a _statement_ or a _function-body_, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Use this function:

```
__asm {
     mov al, 2
     mov dx, 0xD007
     out dx, al
}
```

Comment: Not a C statement, but a proprietary compiler directive.

Answer (score 2):

`{ }`

At least 15 characters are required to post an answer...

Answer (score 1):

```
if (i=2) {} // give `i` a value
```

Answer (score 1):

Even whole program (my GNU C built it despite result code returned is undefined).
The question is WHY?

```
/* NEVER DO THIS!!! */
int main()
{
    {}
}
```

And in C++ we even can stabilize return code by this simple stack trick with variable
(yes, it is dirty, I understand but I think it should work for most cases):

```
/* NEVER RELY ON SUCH TRICKS */
int main()
{
   if (int i=0) {}
}
```

Comment: the why is backward compatibility, I guess. It will just issue a warning.

Comment: Not quite. In C++, if main() doesn't have a return statement, it's guaranteed to return 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main()
{
  // This executes a statement without a semicolon
  if( int i = 10 )
  {      
    // Call a function
    if( Fibonacci(i) ) {}
  }

  // I have made my point
  return 0;
}

int Fibonacci(int n)
{
  return (n == 2) ? 1 : Fibonacci(n - 2) + Fibonacci(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define _ ;

int main()
{
   return 0 _
}
```